# Boolean Difference between text files on Linux?

Tags: file, text, boolean, diff

Are there any command line linux utilities that will give me the boolean difference between two text files?

Meaning:

File-A:

```
Apple  
Pear  
Orange   
Banana
```

File-B:

```
Pear  
Orange
```

Running

```
% program File-A File-B -o output
```

output:

```
Apple  
Banana
```

Edit:

Awesome, thanks guys!

Comment: I count this as shell script programming.

Comment: Could there be items in file2 that are not in file1? If not, why do you call it the 'boolean difference'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
comm -2 -3 File-A File-B > output
```

This assumes that the files are sorted. Check `man comm` for more information.

Comment: To sort them (bash syntax): `comm -3 <(sort -u File-A) <(sort -u File-B)`

Answer (score 1):

The comm  command is what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
comm -3 file1.txt file2.txt | sed -r 's/^\t//'
```

This also catches items in file2 that are not in file 1.